# MFC dialogs caption fails with Unicode

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc, caption, mbcs

I am trying to use Win32 functions like MessageBox or GetOpenFileName in Unicode mode but the caption always shows `??????????????`. I have resources in different languages like Chinese or Hindi and all works well except for standard dialog functions.

I do use the W version, and I have tried it in both MBCS and Unicode linked libraries with no success. I can build my own MessageBoxW, but can't afford rewriting file or folder pick functions.

The typical call is as simple as:
[image]

Note the title is conveniently defined in Unicode with some Hindi characters. This can be seen with the debugger on the ofn structure:
[image]

But the dialog caption does not show the Hindi string
[image]

The dialog behind shows the right strings, in Hindi and Chinese besides latin characters, and it is built with the old Win32 dialog calls in a MBCS linked DLL. See though the comment below.

The front dialog is built in Unicode MFC linked DLL.

The odd thing is that normal dialogs built with Win32 or with MFC fail the same way with SetWindowTextW on the dialog handle. SetWindowTextW works fine on dialog items, and SetDlgItemTextW, works fine too. It is the dialog caption that does not work.

I found, though, a workaround: Instead of SetWindowTextW I use DefWindowProcW.
[image]

Hasn't anyone stumbled into this before ???

Comment: Show code as text, not screen shots. As for your question, make sure the source files are being saved in a Unicode format (go to file -> save as, bring up the Save button's drop-down and select "Save with encoding" and from the character set list make sure a Unicode format is selected).

Comment: What is your setting in Project>Properties>Advanced Character set? Is it `Use Unicode Character Set` or `Use Multi-Byte Character Set`?

Comment: [It’s okay to be contrary, but you need to be consistently contrary: Going against the ambient character set](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20211210-00/?p=106021).

Comment: Can you run the Spy++ tool to check if the dialogs you display are Unicode? If not, the system will convert the strings to multibyte, and use the default codepage for the conversion.

Comment: Code files are saved as UTF8, this is not the problem, resource strings are load from other files and converted to Unicode. All dialogs built with WIn32 or MFC work fine except for those that come from the system like MessageBoxW

Comment: Project settings are set loading Unicode character set libraries. But that does not seem to be the issue. MessageBoxW is available independently from the character set chosen, and both environments fail

Comment: Another odd thing is that MFC tooltips do not work in Unicode. Linking the "U" libraries makes no difference.

MFC toolbars do not work, calls like . Even linking Unicode libraries - otherwise MFC is only available in MBCS - 

The CMFCButton tooltips do not work either. Its tooltip is set with a call that is defined with *LPCTSTR* parameter when the DLL is linked to Unicode:

**void CMFCButton::SetTooltip(LPCTSTR lpszToolTipText)**

I have built my own tooltips, like the MessageBox, these features can easily be made. But file or folder pick dialogs are not that small thing to replicate

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the Spy++. Unfortunatelly it hangs when quering the window properties. I'll keep ploughing on this.

Comment: Got Spy++ working but it reports no useful info. Window Proc is (Unavailable), and caption strings show the ?????????????. No help.

Comment: Tested the "Open" and "About" dialogs as well as the main windows of several applications with Spy++ (used the Find Window tool, with the target) and it always shows the "Window Proc" address. It may also display a (Subclassed) and/or (Unicode) mark (the latter of course means a Unicode window). It is important that the window is Unicode, otherwise it can only display correctly strings containing characters in the system ANSI codepage. For several windows control types Unicode support can be explicitly set eg check LVM_SETUNICODEFORMAT or TVM_SETUNICODEFORMAT. Not sure about dialogs though.